# ListView is not aligned even after added layout_weight

Tags: android, listview

Here is the output of my code. I cannot get all views aligned in each ListView item. I already used layout_weight for each view and also set the layout_width to 0sp. Really curious about why it cannot work. Hope to get some solutions. Thank you!

[image]

**list_item.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="95sp">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/download"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12sp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:adjustViewBounds="false"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_marginLeft="12sp">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:text="name"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="20sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/new_age"
            android:text="New Age"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:text="Email"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp"/>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/phone"
            android:text="Phone"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textSize="16sp"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/countdown"
        android:text="Tomorrow"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="16sp"
        android:textSize="16sp"/>
```

...

```
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You should first use layout_weightSum in your parent layout and then add layout_weight to your child layouts.

Comment: One more thing, you used sp for layout_height. Use dp.
    android:layout_height="95dp"  . Use sp for font size.

Answer (score 0):

> You need to add `layout_weightSum` in your parent layout -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="95dp"
    android:weightSum="4"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12sp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:adjustViewBounds="false"
    android:scaleType="fitXY" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12sp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:text="name"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/new_age"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:text="New Age"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:text="Email"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/phone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        tools:text="Phone"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView

        android:id="@+id/countdown"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        tools:text="Tomorrow"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/daysago"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        tools:text="4 days ago"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

You need to then equally distribute the weight by using `android:layout_weight="1"` on each of the child layouts.

Let me know if you need more help.

Comment: Add it to the second LinearLayout as well

Comment: Don't add the android:weightSum to the first LinearLayout, add it to the one after the ImageView

Comment: now the alignment is not equal horizontally, not vertically. so how can i add weightSum?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/151181/discussion-between-hsm59-and-yoyo97).

Answer (score 0):

Use this :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="95dp"
android:weightSum="4"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/image"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12sp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:adjustViewBounds="false"
    android:scaleType="fitCenter"
    android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="12sp"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="name"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/new_age"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Age"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/email"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Email"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/phone"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Phone"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView

    android:id="@+id/countdown"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="16sp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="Tomorrow"
    android:textSize="16sp" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/daysago"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="16sp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="4days ago"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
</LinearLayout>


</LinearLayout>
```